# How could I achieve this vertical line with a small title like this

Tags: vertical

[image]

How can I obtain this vertical line?

Comment: Welcome to TeX:SE! Please show us in form of complete, compilable small document, what you try so far. Seems that use `tcolorbox` can be a way to solve your problem.

Comment: Can you rewrite your title to be more descriptive than "I want something like this"? Also, provide more context; Should there be multiple of these structures following one another? Should it be allowed to break at the page boundary?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{framed,lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]
    \begin{leftbar}
        \noindent
        \lipsum[2]
    \end{leftbar}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

**Second solution**:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{framed,lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{tabular}{|lp{10cm}}
\textit{Proof}:& \lipsum[1]\\
& \lipsum[5]
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this reply. A question the lp 10 cm represent the length of the vertical lign. How should i know exactly the size of it?

Comment: @Ravinata No, 10 cm is the width of text for proof, You can change this value as You need, also to reach the width of Your page . Length of the vertical line is equal to the length of Your proof.

Comment: Simple and effective !